# Haskell profiling - clock_gettime

Tags: haskell, profiling, clock

I'm running a Haskell program that does a long computation. After some profiling and tracing, I noticed the following:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -v ./hl test.hl
9000045000050000
Command being timed: "./hl test.hl +RTS"
User time (seconds): 1.43
System time (seconds): 1.15
```

It was using a lot of system time even though my code does not explicitly invoke any system calls (it reads a file and interprets some code in it).

Running it with strace -ttT shows a lot of calls to a timer:

```
17:04:52.454513 clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, {1, 282721271}) = 0 <0.000529>
17:04:52.456223 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000720>
17:04:52.458749 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT], [], 8) = 0 <0.000239>
17:04:52.460288 clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, {1, 285126436}) = 0 <0.000255>
17:04:52.461650 --- SIGVTALRM {si_signo=SIGVTALRM, si_code=SI_TIMER, si_pid=0, si_uid=0, si_value=0} ---
17:04:52.462242 rt_sigreturn()          = 0 <0.000458>
```

I thought it might be the [RTS clock](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html), so I disabled it and re-run:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -v ./hl test.hl +RTS -V0
9000045000050000
Command being timed: "./hl test.hl +RTS -V0"
User time (seconds): 1.73
System time (seconds): 0.85
```

The strace output seems almost identical except for the actual SIGVTALRM:

```
17:05:16.409729 clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, {0, 155881514}) = 0 <0.000378>
17:05:16.410746 clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {2184631, 597586194}) = 0 <0.000432>
17:05:16.412724 clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, {0, 156994988}) = 0 <0.000290>
17:05:16.413832 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000245>
17:05:16.415017 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT], [], 8) = 0 <0.000305>
```

I have a few questions:

1. Why is Haskell calling clock_gettime repeatedly?
2. Is there any way to disable this functionality?

Comment: though it is not a solution to your problem, but did you look at criterion - for profiling?

Comment: Are you running with profiling? Profiling does extra work.

Comment: @GarethR: I made sure I'm running without profiling, even created a new cabal sandbox to be sure of that fact.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at where `clock_gettime` is called in the GHC RTS and found that it is used in a call to `getMonotonicTime` that in turn is the basis of the timeouts in the [TimerManager](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/380b25ea4754c2aea683538ffdb179f8946219a0/libraries/base/GHC/Event/TimerManager.hs) of the `GHC.Event` library that is used by the IO Manager for polling on handles, files, system calls, etc. The [MIO](http://haskell.cs.yale.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/hask035-voellmy.pdf) paper is a good relatively recent resource on the IO Manager. In any case, I don't imagine you will be able to eliminate those calls.

Also note that while you see *lots* of those clock calls, that does not mean they are the system calls which are taking the most *time*, which I imagine relate more to GC, actually performing IO, etc.